# Searching for a file that ends with a particular suffix, moving it and changing the surffix

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I need a bash script/ command to search for all the files in the working directory end in `_sh`, move them to a folder `./Folder` and change the suffix `_sh` to `_priv`

I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction

Comment: I don't believe any of the code you show is germane to your question. Also, you make it very hard to read by using such deeply nested paths in what I presume is your actual question at the end - can't you simplify that to something like *"I want to rename `a/b/c/fred*` as `a/b/c/elephant_sh`"* or somesuch?

Comment: Thanks will edit @MarkSetchell

Comment: If you want to search all subdirectories as well, `find` is generally your choice, (e.g. `find /path -type f -name "*_sh"`). That will find the files, (which you use to feed a loop). Then you will generally want to use a *parameter expansion* (most efficient) or call `basename` and `dirname` to separate the path and filenames. Another *parameter expansion* to remove the `_sh` and replace with `_priv` as part of the `mv` command. (Search *parameter expansion with substring removal* or see `man bash` under `"Parameter Expansion"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple bash script to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *_sh; do                             # Loop over all files ending in _sh
    mv "$file" "${PWD}/Folder/${file%_sh}_priv"  # Move files to Folder with new suffix
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying to move the files to `~/.hfc-key-store/`. When I replace your code with `mv "$file" "~/.hfc-key-store/${file%_sk}_priv"` it fails with a mv: rename `69eac65d8c672fa9db4663fb6a00dc9497b89fd9db10b1e46965e2382adf6f9c_sk to ~/.hfc-key-store/69eac65d8c672fa9db4663fb6a00dc9497b89fd9db10b1e46965e2382adf6f9c_priv: No such file or directory`  but when I do it manually it works. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you format your comment with code blocks? It's hard to read

Comment: 1) in the question you wanted to rename `_sh` suffix not `_sk` 2) if that's not the error, show your manual code for one file

Comment: I think `${PWD}/` is unnecessary, just `mv "$file" Folder/...` is easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `rename` installed (a.k.a Perl rename), you can do it very simply with a one-liner, including making the target directory:

```
rename --dry-run --mkpath 's|^|Folder/|; s|_sh$|_priv|' *_sh
```

**Sample Output**

```
'other_sh' would be renamed to 'Folder/other_priv'
'sample1_sh' would be renamed to 'Folder/sample1_priv'
```

When you become more familiar with the switches, that will become even shorter:

```
rename -p 's|^|Folder/|; s|_sh$|_priv|' *_sh
```

If you are not that familiar with Perl, there are two substitutions going on in the middle there, separated by a comma:

```
rename -p ' SUBSTITUTION1 ; SUBSTITUTION2 ' *.sh
```

The first substitution replaces `^` (which means *"start of line"*) with the prefix `Folder/`.

The second substitution replaces `_sh` at the end of the line (`$`) with `_priv`.

Apart from all the power of the Perl code you can use, `rename` has the added benefit of being able to do dry-runs so you can test your code, and also being able to create output directories and warn you if multiple files would converge onto the same name and cause data loss.

---

For any macOS users, `rename` is most simply installed with **homebrew** as follows:

```
brew install rename
```